# Date time interval in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a Column called `CrateDate`, I want to retrieve records whose CreateDate is last two days. How can I do that? 
My failed attempt is this :

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] WHERE City = 'Paris' AND CreateDate >= '2016-12-07' AND CreateDate <= '2016-12-10'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find records from previous x days?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782999/find-records-from-previous-x-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DATEADD()` function to substract the number of days from the current date to get that many days old data:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE City = 'Paris'
    AND CreateDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Or even the simpler (works *at least* for 2008R2 and up), since you're subtracting days:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE City = 'Paris'
    AND CreateDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-2 AND GETDATE()
```

If you want to have a finer-grained interval, like 40 hours, then you have to use `DATEADD()`, otherwise you can stick to the implicit subtraction of the number of days you want to go back from my second query.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATEADD` to subtract 2 days from the current date and check that Created Date is between that and today's date:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
  WHERE City = 'Paris' AND CreateDate
      BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE()
```

If you want whole days (i.e. no time component then use this):

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
  WHERE City = 'Paris' AND CreateDate
      BETWEEN  dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,DATEADD(day, -2, GETUTCDATE())))
  AND DATEADD(s, -1, dateadd(dd,0, dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,DATEADD(day, 1, GETUTCDATE()))))
```

If the current date is 09-Dec-2016 then the where clause of the second query would generate:

```
CreateDate BETWEEN 07-Dec-2016 00:00:00 and 09-Dec-2016 23:59:59
```

> Note: Use `GETDATE()` if your date times are stored in local time or `GETUTCDATE()` if stored in UTC.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why UTC date rather than server date?

Comment: @3N1GM4 habit I always store all dates in my databases in UTC - it just makes things so much simpler when users from around the world want to see dates in their own timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [DATEDIFF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189794.aspx) and [GETDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188383.aspx)

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
WHERE City = 'Paris' 
  AND DATEDIFF(DAY,CreateDate,GETDATE()) between 0 and 2
```

This will only check the date-part of `CreateDate` and ignore the time. (That means if you run the query on `'2016-12-09 10:11'`, it will also get data with `CreateDate='2016-12-07 08:17'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
WHERE City = 'Paris' AND CreateDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),-2) 
      AND CreateDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

dateadd() and getdate()

```
select count(*)
from MyTable
where City = 'Paris'
and CreateDate between dateadd(dd,-2, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
  select count(*) FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
  WHERE City = 'Paris' 
  and CreateDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

If the all records saved in the same time zone with server, so below is OK：

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
WHERE City = 'Paris' AND CreateDate >= DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE())
```

If the records saved in different time zones, maybe need know the exaclty timezone every city. If did not save the corresponding time zone, use the UTC maybe a better way:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE City = 'Paris' AND CreateDate >= DATEADD(day, -2, GETUTCDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from MyTable
where CreateDate between dateadd(dd,-2, getdate()) and getdate() and City = 'Paris'
```